# Long name of Chapter in TOC. Doesn't work \\ for a new line

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking

For a `\documentclass{report}`, how can I make a long chapter name to wrap onto a second line in TOC ?

For example :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not also working in TOC. It doesn't show anything different

Comment: add `\raggedright` before the table of contents. The command should be worked local.

Comment: I need it to be like above. I included the package tocloft, and I wrote \chapter[Really Really Really Really \\ Really Really Long Text]{Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long Text} and it still didn't work

Comment: @A.Ellett sorry `\\ ` is not fragile, it is declared as `\DeclareRobustCommand\\{....` so my comment was nonsense, I'll delete thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually line breaks are permitted in the table of contents.
Example from Marco Daniel:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long Text}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Package `hyperref`

If you are using package `hyperref` with a driver that does not support broken links across lines, then option `linktocpage` helps. That allows line breaks in the title and the link is put to the page number instead.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really
Really Really Long Text}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Other classes packages

My guess with package `hyperref` can be wrong, the screen shot in the question does not show hyper links and the chapter title is set in all uppercase letters, perhaps the questioner is using a special class or package that deals with the table of contents that prevents line breaks.

### Justification

Or line breaks are permitted and the effect is just an ordinary overfull `\hbox` because TeX cannot find a good break point.

Comment: Is `latex`-`dvips`-`ps2pdf` the only non supported driver? In this case the package `hypdvips` is a good choice?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks, example added. E.g., all `pdfmark` drivers and `dviwindo` do not support `breaklinks`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Sorry, you have deleted the answer, I wanted to vote :-(. Your answer is as valid as mine without any further information of Cipriana. My guess can be wrong, the screen shot does not show hyper links and the chapter title is in all uppercase, perhaps the questioner is using a special class or package that deals with the table of contents.

Comment: You can add this information too. Two answers using a crystal ball seem to be less useful for other users.